# Why are there such strange comments in the documentation for Linphone's MediaDirection type?

Tags: linphone, linphone-sdk

It seems that they missed when they wrote comments. And this is repeated everywhere, and not just in the implementation for any particular platform. And the question arises - to trust the documentation or the names of the variables?

- [java](https://download.linphone.org/releases/docs/liblinphone/latest/java/org/linphone/core/MediaDirection.html)
  [image]
- [c#](https://download.linphone.org/releases/docs/liblinphone/4.5/cs/api/Linphone.MediaDirection.html)
  [image]
- [swift](https://download.linphone.org/releases/docs/liblinphone/latest/swift/Enums/MediaDirection.html#/s:10linphonesw14MediaDirectionO8SendOnlyyA2CmF)
- [python](https://pythonhosted.org/linphone/api_reference.html)
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing that out!

It seems to be a wrapper documentation issue as the source file is correct: https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/liblinphone/-/blob/master/include/linphone/types.h#L749

I'll see what I can do to fix it.

Comment: I've made the fix, it is available in release/5.2 branch, docs will be updated by nightly build tonight.
Cheers!

Comment: I see that the documentation for java has already been updated.

Comment: C# and Swift are also fixed right now.
Python wrapper no longer exists so it won't be updated.